# Are "Shopify's Liquid" and "Siteleaf Liquid" the same?

Tags: liquid

I see two sites for the Liquid lang, seems it is one lang:

- Shopify: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/
- Siteleaf: https://www.siteleaf.com/blog/tags/liquid/

Are they the same language? If not, what is most popular? Seems Shopify's because it's used in the Jekyll tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think they are the same.

On the homepage the paragraph:

```
"Benefit from a large open source community. Use any 
 existing Jekyll theme, or write your own using Liquid, 
 Sass, and CoffeeScript. Develop locally and even offline."
```

The word "liquid" links to https://shopify.github.io/liquid/ suggesting they are using Shopify's liquid.